# VB.NET & simple Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've got an extremely simple regular expression contained in a subroutine:

```
Private Sub txtSubject_Leave() Handles txtSubject.Leave
    Dim pattern As String = "^[A-Z0-9]*"
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(txtSubject.Text, pattern) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Subject")
        txtSubject.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm sure it's going to be something simple but every string I try that is erroneous wont return the error message, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a few examples of the strings you are using as input, which you expect to fail the match?

Comment: Regex's are fiddly and sometimes tricky to get right (even the small ones). Try using a tool to test them such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/), its much easier than testing them at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[A-Z0-9]*
```

Matches 0 or more alphanumeric characters at the start of the string you are trying to match. The `0` part is important here, because if the first character of the string is a space, the 0 will 'match' and pass your test. If you want to make sure that the first character is alphanumeric, use another quantifier, like `+`:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+
```

If you want to make sure that the string contains only alphanumeric characters, use the end of line anchor as well:

```
^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

In this particular situation, if you also want to allow an empty string, then you can use `*`:

```
^[A-Z0-9]*$
```

This one will not allow non-alphanumeric characters either.

Comment: Thank you, I just needed the end of line anchor, I need a bit more practice with regex I think.

Comment: @LismUK You're welcome! And don't worry, regex takes some time to get used to :)